# AngularJS: Use route for given URL when loading page first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application

I develop SPA using AngularJS. My config looks like this:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider",
    function($routeProvider) {
        return $routeProvider
            .when("/", {
                redirectTo: "/clients"
            }).when("/clients", {
                templateUrl: "app/views/crm/clients/list.html"
            }).when("/client/:id?", {
                templateUrl: "app/views/crm/clients/edit.html"
            }).when("/404", {
                templateUrl: "app/views/pages/404.html"
            }).otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/404"
            });
    }
]);
```

I would like to let my users share URLs for clients: `http://myapp.com/#/client/1`, `http://myapp.com/#/client/2` etc. The idea is that user writes URL to location bar and gets to client page for a specific client.

When I tried to listen for `$routeChangeStart` event I found out that `current` parameter in event callback is empty when page is loaded for first time and `next.$$route.originalPath` is always `/`.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
      console.log(current);                   // undefined
      console.log(next.$$route.originalPath); // /
      console.log(next.$$route.redirectTo);   // /clients
});
```

So how can I get the original URL sent to server to use route requested?

**UPDATE**

As it turned out, the problem was in my own redirect that was triggered when user session token from cookies was extracted. It redirected to `/` every user who entered application with session cookie.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
document.URL
```

or

```
$window.location
```

ie:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
     console.log(document.URL);   
     console.log($window.location)       

});
```

Please see demo here
http://plnkr.co/edit/oaW40vWewxdZYxRkCW8c?p=preview

Comment: document.URL holds the value needed only when listening to `$locationChangeStart` event.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came up with solution which looks like *dirty hack* yet works.

```
var app = angular.module('app', [ ... ]);

app.run(function (...) {

    ...

    var firstTimeLocationChanged = true;
    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        var savedPath = current.split('#').slice(-1);
        if (firstTimeLocationChanged && ['/', '/login'].indexOf(savedPath) < 0) {
            firstTimeLocationChanged = false;
            setTimeout(function() {
                console.log('redirect to: ' + savedPath);
                $location.path(savedPath);
            }, 3000);
        }
    });

    ...

});
```

**UPDATE**

As it turned out, the problem was in my own redirect that was triggered when user session token from cookies was extracted. It redirected to `/` every user who entered application with session cookie. So the solution above is not needed at all.